# Facebook like button for item not a link

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I can create a Facebook like button easily enough to like a URL but what I can't do is get it to like an item in a Facebook page.

So for example in this link (https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=347060885316097&set=t.540015414) is a picture and you can like it. But if I was to place that URL inside a LIKE button and click that I'm liking the page and not the item.

So any ideas on how to create a button to like an item rather than the link?

Answer (score 0):

See the Facebook API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Using their generated code will show you what is really required. They show you a link to an iFrame with parameters that you can use for the actual item being liked (the web page or the Url to the picture in each of those cases).

GL.

Comment: The problem is the like button plugin does not seem to work with internal facebook photo urls. It will generate a like button, but try with a photo that already has likes and you'll see it's not connected. I to am searching for a solution for this.